# sshfs -o follow_symlinks mounts with broken softlinks

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, symlink, sshfs

Up until a day ago I was perfectly able to mount a drive via sshfs with the `follow_symlinks` option given.
In fact I set up an alias for this command and used it for several weeks.

Since yesterday, using the same alias the volume still mounts correctly but the all the soft symlinks within that volume are broken.
Logging in using a regular ssh session confirms the symlinks actually are functioning.

Are there any configuration files that may interfere with what I try to do?
I was modifying `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `/etc/hosts` because I experienced severe login delays when starting an ssh session from a friend's place. But I reverted any changes later on.

Could a wrong configuration in these files cause my issue?
Btw. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the permissions on the particular machine I was trying to mount the folder from changed over the weekend.
It is now only allowing access to certain folders from within the same network. That is why my soft-links (pointing to now permission restricted content) seemed broken when mounting from my home network.